# React Native (iOS): RCTEventEmitter before javascript is loaded

Tags: javascript, react-native, ibeacon

I have a problem implementing beacons in my app. I am using the library `react-native-beacons-manager`, but I think is a general "problem".

The issue is that when I kill my app (and this is important to reproduce the issue) and I get closer to my beacon, iOS fire an event `regionDidEnter` that is caught by a file wrote in native code, and then, sent to javascript using the method of `RCTEventEmitter`: `[self sendEventWithName:@"regionDidEnter" body:event];`

The problem is that this event is fired before javascript is fully loaded, so my listener:

```
// component.js
Beacons.BeaconsEventEmitter.addListener('regionDidEnter', b => {
        //code
      });
```

doesn't get called.

Order of events:

```
[BeaconsDemo] Did finish launching enter
[BeaconsDemo] Did finish launching After jsBundleURLForBundleRoot
[BeaconsDemo] Did finish launching After RCTRootView alloc
[BeaconsDemo] Did finish launching After UIWindow alloc
[BeaconsDemo] Did finish launching After makeKeyAndVisible
[BeaconsDemo] Did finish launching end
--iOS send the event and it is caught by RNiBeacon but it has no listeners yet--
[BeaconsDemo] no listeners in RnIBeacon.m
--Register
[BeaconsDemo] regionDidExit
-- First line of javascript --
[BeaconsDemo] start observing
[BeaconsDemo] requestAlwaysAuth
```

Any idea to handle this situation? Is there any way or approach to send the event through `RCTEventEmitter` waiting for the javascript is loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This general problem also exists when writing native beacon apps for iOS or Android.  The solution is that you must set up your "hook" that enables beacon monitoring and adds the event listener (or delegate / notification callback as it is called in native code) in the appropriate place per platform:

**iOS:**  `AppDelegate.didFinishLanching(options: )`

**Android:** `Application.onCreate()`

The key is that this setup must be complete before those methods return.

This same rule applies for ReactNative.  The trick with ReactNative, is that by default JavaScript does not run on these events -- it runs only when a screen is launched, which sets up the hook too late for the above to work when your app is killed.  To get this to work, you'll need to eject your app so you can set up some custom native code in the above callbacks.

Two options:

1. Implement beacon detection natively (easiest, but requires native coding on a per-platform basis)
2. Add native code in the above native callbacks that starts a `RCTBridge` on iOS, and launches a view that executes code that triggers our JavaScript code to set up beacon detection.  On Android, the equivalent would be to construct a new ReactRootView and ReactNativeInstanceManager in a way that it triggers your JavaScript code to set up beacon detection.

I have not personally tested option 2 to see if it can set up the hooks soon enough.  If it works, it will certainly be harder than the native solution, but allows you to keep your beacon detection logic in JavaScript.

Comment: hummmmm but the library react-native-beacons-manager is implemented using native code as you can see:

https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/blob/master/ios/RNiBeacon/RNiBeacon/RNiBeacon.m

Maybe I am not understanding well your answer?

Comment: i.e, the option two is very similar to the implementation of the library, my AppDelegate.didFinishLanching(options: ) is starting my app and, so, the RCTBridge, no?

Comment: The key point is that even if the RCTBridge is started and the view load starts before the end of the didFinishLaunching method, does your javascript code execute before then?  It must set up your monitored regions before didFinishLaunching exits.  You might be able to add logging (in your code and at the end of didFinishLaunching) to find out.

Comment: Hi, yes... Seems that javascript code is executed after receiving the event (for example regionDidEnter). I have updated my question with the order of the events that I receive. As you can see, Javascript code is loaded after receiving the event but I don't know how can I write my AppDelegate.m to load my javascript soon. Any idea? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

(https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/issues/50)

I've forked @newoceaninfosys' fork and added the 'missed beacon' method. Check my last 3 commits for how to replicate it.
(https://github.com/iamandiradu/react-native-beacons-manager)
Use it by adding this in your didMount function:

`if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    // iOS cold start listener
    this.beaconMissedListener = Beacons.BeaconsEventEmitter.addListener(
        'onMissedBeacon',
        data => {
            if (data) {
                this._beaconListener(data);
            }
        },
    );
    Beacons.getMissedBeacon();
}`

This will retrieve the data that got 'lost' because the event triggered faster than the listener.

([React Native (iOS): RCTEventEmitter before javascript is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200471/react-native-ios-rcteventemitter-before-javascript-is-loaded))

Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You **need to be aware the listeners exist on JavaScript side**. You can solve this by using [this example on react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript). The important property is `hasListeners`, this will be toggled to `true` after listener is registered on React Native JavaScript side.
2. Problem, what to do if event has to be sent to JavaScript side, but it still **has no listeners on JavaScript side**, so the **event will be lost**...? You can solve this by adding adding something like exponentialBackoff in swift:

```
func exponentialBackoff(maxRetries: Int, initialDelay: TimeInterval, task: @escaping (_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    var retries = 0
    var delay = initialDelay

    func attempt() {
        task { success in
            if success {
                print("Task succeeded.")
            } else {
                retries += 1
                if retries > maxRetries {
                    print("Task failed after \(maxRetries) retries.")
                    failure()
                } else {
                    print("Task failed, retrying in \(delay) seconds...")
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                        delay *= 2 // Double the delay for exponential backoff
                        attempt()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    attempt()
}
```

3. Add a block of code that sends this event to JavaScript side but consumes this `exponentialBackoff` pattern to make sure the event will eventually be sent to JavaScript side when `hasListeners` is toggled to `true`. Tweak this function invocation to suit your case, in this example the code that sends will try to send in 0.1s, 0.2s, 0.4s, 0.8s, 1.6s, 3.2s, 6.4s, 12.8s, 25.4s, 50.8s... :)

```
exponentialBackoff(maxRetries: 10, initialDelay: 0.1) { completion in
            guard let emitter = RNEventEmitterModule.emitter, RNEventEmitterModule.hasListeners else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            emitter.sendEvent(withName: "onReady", body: arguments)
            completion(true)
        } failure: {
            print("All retries failed.")
        }
```